# row adds two times jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i am trying to add a single row in my table... but the following code adds a row twice at the end of each row...ie., i i am getting two similar rows instead of a single row

```
DefaultTableModel tb=(DefaultTableModel)tb1.getModel();
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db","root","");
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
int a=(Integer) l1.getSelectedValue();
System.out.println(a);
String query="select * from student where rno ="+a+";";
System.out.println(query);
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()){
    int rno=rs.getInt("rno");
    String name=rs.getString("name");
    String sec= rs.getString("sec");
    tb.insertRow(0,new Object[]{name,rno,name,sec});
    tb1.setModel(tb);
```

Comment: Are you sure your ResultSet doesn't have the duplicate data?

Comment: You don't seem to remove any existing data from the table model before adding new data

Answer (score 0):

Put this call **after** the loop, not in the loop:

```
tb1.setModel(tb);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need *at all* to set the model to the table. You're already casting `DefaultTableModel`, and unless your getting a casting exception, the table should already hold a `DefaultTableModel`. So all you need is to `addRow(row)` or `insetRow(index, row);`. No need to set the model, the table will update automatically through its `DefaultTableModel`